# Using "find" command to find files with unknown combination of spaces and underscores as word separators?

Tags: regex, shell, find

I'm writing a script that goes through a database and matches items in the database against corresponding files in the filesystem. The problem I've having is that a space in an item title (from the DB) may correspond to **either a space or one or more underscores** in the corresponding filename. (eg. "Some name" may be "Some name.jpg", "Some_name.jpg", or "Some__name.jpg"). The casing may also be different, so I need the search to be case insensitive.

I've been using the following command, which works fine for the first two cases above, but fails to find files where a space is represented by a double underscore:

```
find . -iname '*Some[ _]name*' -print
```

...I've tried various things I'd expect to work, like `[ _]+` and `([ _]+)`, but with no luck. If anyone can tell me how to specify "some spaces or underscores" using `find` I'd be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify the platform? The easy answers here require GNU find, and may not work on platforms with only a POSIX-baseline implementation.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: I've tested the variant given in my comment on Avinesh's answer. If you're continuing to see things not work for you, I suggest that you should edit your question to include some **exact** examples of commands that create files that the existing suggestions won't find.

Comment: ...for instance, I started with `touch 'some__name.txt' 'Some Name.txt'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `-iname` is a pattern/glob not a regular expression.

You want to use `-iregex` instead.

Something like this:

```
find . -iregex '.*Some\( \|_+\)name.*' -print
```

or:

```
find . -regextype posix-awk -iregex '.*Some( |_+).*' -print
```

Comment: careful with `e*` and also op wants single space or one or more underscores.

Answer (score 3):

> either a space or one or more underscores

```
find . -regextype sed -iregex '.*Some\( \|_\+\)name.*'
```

Comment: Why pick a regex type where you need that much escaping?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `either a space or one or more underscores`

Comment: Again, a comment I'd withdrawn before any response. `find . -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*Some( |_+)name.*'`, on the other hand, _does_ work.

Comment: or `find . -regextype posix-egrep -iregex '.*Some( |_+)name.*'`

Comment: Thanks all. That did it. I find the `posix-extended` or `posix-egrep` versions much more readable than `sed`, but they all do the job.